# Git: folder with colons in them cannot be build using cygwin

Tags: windows, git, github, cygwin, git-bash

We have a repository which has colons in some of the folder names. During the build process, folder name will be with colon. These generate an error when building on windows using cygwin or git bash.

It gives this error:

```
Execution failed. Reason: Illegal char <:> at index 32: build/solution/Persisten
ce Layer: MySQL or Oracle.xml
```

What are the ways I can fix this issue? I tried by installing WSL but that has some limitation in terms path.

Please help on this.

Comment: Technically, Windows doesn't reserve ":" in filepaths. It has to be allowed in general, both for device names and for named file streams (e.g. "filename:streamname:streamtype"), if a filesystem supports named streams (e.g. NTFS). Due to the latter, ":" is disallowed in filenames in all of Microsoft's filesystems. Some third-party filesystems do allow ":", such as "VBoxSharedFolderFS" for a VirtualBox shared folder. Of course that means next to nothing if high-level libraries and programs hard code assumptions about what's allowed.

Comment: Don't use Windows probably?

Comment: WSL might meet your needs, but it isn't clear what you mean by “some limitation in terms of path.”

Comment: Yes I am bale to checkout the code using WSL but as folder name contains : it comes in a different way. And while building it is not able find the path from WSL.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: @matzeri, to clarify, the characters a filesystem must reserve in names are null ('\0'), path separators '\' and '/', and wildcards '*', '?', '<' (`DOS_STAR`), '>' (`DOS_QM`), and '"' (`DOS_DOT`). If a filesystem doesn't support the wildcards, then its support for `FindFirstFile` is broken. But nothing at the API level prevents a filesystem from allowing ":", "|", and control characters 1-31. The linked rules for applications disallow them because MS filesystems (e.g. NTFS, FAT32) do. But the VirtualBox shared-folder filesystem allows them anyway to facilitate working with a Unix host.

Comment: @ErykSun But cygwin use win32 system call so it can not use `:` for any file name. And git for windows reuse the cygwin/msys structure so it can not also. If you want a source code to be interoperable with Windows you can not use `:` as part of a file name.

Comment: @matzeri, nothing at the API level stops us from using ":" in a filename. It *cannot* because some filesystems support [file streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams) -- e.g. "path\to\filename:streamname:streamtype". Some libraries and applications may reject such a name, but then they're not even compatible with what is a completely valid Windows file path. That's not uncommon, unfortunately.

Comment: @ErykSun Do you know that Windows explorer and CMD are two examples of application that rejects such name ? So in Windows for all general usage that character is unusable. What is the scope to be able to create a file name not usable by most of the windows application ? I assume that using git on Windows means that Arindam want to do something in Windows with those files.

Comment: @matzeri, yes, CMD's filename parsing inherits DOS rules that assume names with colon in them are device names, which makes working even with completely allowed file streams impossible without hacks. The shell API (Explorer) isn't much better. I'll add that if you mount a VirtualBox shared-folder filesystem in an NTFS directory, for some reason NTFS parses past the mount point, which is none of its business, and fails a create/open as an invalid name. But with just the VirtualBox filesystem itself (via UNC or drive), I have no problems using ":" in a regular Windows process with C or Python.